# Pointers and References - Simple CharArray Manipulation Program

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I'm trying to write a program in C++ which goes through a char array, replacing ch1 with ch2 as it goes along, the problem I am having is getting it to change the actual string which is inputed rather than return a new string. In C# you would use "ref" but I'm confused how to do this in c++, would you need a * or &?

The code below has lots of errors:

(7): error C2664: 'strlen' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char' to 'const char *' Conversion from integral type to pointer type requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

(7): error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'char *' to 'char []' There are no conversions to array types, although there are conversions to references or pointers to arrays

(11): error C2100: illegal indirection

(17): error C2100: illegal indirection

(24): error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'char []' to 'char' There is no context in which this conversion is possible

(36): error C2664: 'replace' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char [17]' to 'char &'

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
int replace(char & str, char ch1, char ch2)
{

    char newStr[]= new char[strlen(str)+1];
    int i=0;
    while(str!='\0')
    {
        if(*str==ch1)
        {
            newStr[i]=ch2;
        }
        else
        { 
            newStr[i]=*str;
        }
        str++;
        i++;
    }

    newStr[i]='\0';
    str = newStr;

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    char str[]="My name is Craig";
    char takeOut='C';
    char changeTo='a';

    cout << "Before: " << str <<endl;
    int changes=replace(str, takeOut, changeTo);
    cout << "After: " << str << endl;

    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In C++ you'd use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and [`std::replace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace):

```
std::string s = "My name is Craig";
std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), 'C', 'a');
```

If for whatever reason you want to implement your own version, taking a pointer to a null terminated string, the main point is that you don't need to create a new string:

```
void replace(char* str, char ch1, char ch2)
{
  while (*str != '\0')
  {
    if (*str == ch1) *str = ch2;
    ++str;
  }
}
```